# Why does function A work and function B throw an error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, pug

I have 2 functions, one works and the other does not - the reason the second function is more important is that essentially I want to be able to change what's in the final array. Deconstruction is great and all but I don't expect to have the same incoming data landing in the same place - elsewhere I fixed this issue by creating individual arrays and just having all my functions return data by index, but I'm a little bamboozled here.

Heres the first one (createLogs) that does what I want it to do and if the data always came, in the same way, would do more than enough.

```
function createLogs(array,runtimeArray) {
  let basicsLog=[]
  array.map(function callback(currentValue,index) {
    let currentRuntime = runtimeArray[index]
    let [,date,time,systemMode,systemSetting,calEvent,ProgramMode,coolSetTemp,heatSetTemp,currentTemp] = currentValue
    basicsLog.push([index,date,time,systemMode,systemSetting,calEvent,ProgramMode,coolSetTemp,heatSetTemp,currentTemp,currentRuntime])
})
console.log(basicsLog)
return basicsLog
}
```

Returns

```
        [ 36,
          2018-11-19T05:00:00.000Z,
          'second failure',
          'heat',
          'heatOff',
          'hold',
          'Sleep',
          70,
          70,
          69.5,
          135 ],
        [ 37,
          2018-11-19T05:00:00.000Z,
          '2:35:00',
          undefined,
          undefined,
          undefined,
          undefined,
          undefined,
          undefined,
          undefined,
          null ] ]
```

Now here is createResults() - I think much better for a situation where what comes in is highly variable (basically its a table , and the columns in the table are different in different situations)

createResults() looks like this:

```
function createResults(originalThermostatArray,dateArray,timeArray, systemSettingsArray, systemModeArray, calendarEventArray, programModeArray, coolSetTempArray, heatSetTempArray, currentTempArray, thermostatTempArray, outdoorTempArray, combinedRuntimesArray) {
    let resultArray = []

    originalThermostatArray.forEach(function(currentValue,index) {
      let currentDate = dateArray[index]
      let currentTime = timeArray[index]
      let currentSystemSetting = systemSettingsArray[index]
      let currentSystemMode = systemModeArray[index]
      let currentCalEvent = calendarEventArray[index]
      let currentProgramMode = programModeArray[index]
      let currentCoolSetTemp = coolSetTempArray[index]
      let currentHeatSetTemp = heatSetTempArray[index]
      let currentAvgTemp = currentTempArray[index]
      let currentThermostatTemp = thermostatTempArray[index]
      let currentOutdoorTemp = outdoorTempArray[index]
      let currentRuntime = combinedRuntimesArray[index]
      resultArray.push([index, currentDate, currentTime, currentSystemSetting, currentSystemMode, currentCalEvent,currentProgramMode, currentCoolSetTemp, currentHeatSetTemp, currentAvgTemp, currentThermostatTemp, currentOutdoorTemp, currentRuntime])

    })
    console.log(resultArray)
    return resultArray
}
```

And Returns

```
 [ 36,
    2018-11-19T05:00:00.000Z,
    'second failure',
    'heat',
    'heatOff',
    'hold',
    'Sleep',
    70,
    70,
    69.5,
    69.5,
    23.5,
    135 ],
  [ 37,
    2018-11-19T05:00:00.000Z,
    '2:35:00',
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    23.5,
    null ] ]
```

On the front end the code looks like this

```
    div.resultSummaries.equipmentSummary
      h1.summaryHeader.equipmentSummaryHead Possible Equipment Failures
      h3.equipmentSummaryBody #{equipresultCount}
      p.equipmentSummaryBody  This table looks for increasing thermostat temperatures during a cooling call.

      table.fullResults.equipmentResultsTable
        caption.equipTitle Possible Equipment Failures Log
          thead
            tr
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Index
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Date
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Time
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   System Setting
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   System Mode
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Calendar Event
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Program Mode
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Cool Set Temp
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Heat Set Temp
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Avg Temp
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Thermostat Temp
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Outdoor Temp
              th.resultHeader.equipmentHeader   Runtime(sec)
            tr

                tbody
                  - let equipFailsResultLog = result.equipLogs;
                      for item in equipFailsResultLog
                        tr.equipRow
                          for item in equipArray
                            td.resultTable.result.equipResult #{item}
                tfoot
```

But createResults() returns this error on the front end:

```
/views/upload.pug:137 135| for item in equipFailsResultLog 136| tr.equipRow > 137| for item in equipArray 138| td.resultTable.result.equipResult #{item} 139| tfoot 140| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
```

I think the fact that they return differently is causing the error but why? note that I tried writing createResults() as a for each and a map

function1 (createlogs) allows me to get into the array and access the individual elements and place them correctly

function2 (createResults) does not..

How can I access the nested elements using function 2 or display them the way I would want to?

added:

create results is called like this

```
const basicLogsArray = returnLogic.createResult(originalThermostatArray,dateArray,timeArray,systemSettingsArray,systemModeArray,calendarEventArray,programModeArray,coolSetTempArray,heatSetTempArray,currentTempArray,thermostatTempArray,outdoorTempArray,combinedRuntimesArray)
```

create log is called similarly but with just array and runtime array.

```
const equipFailsLogs = reportLogic.rowsByIndex(
    basicLogsArray,
    possibleEquipmentFailuresArray
  )

  console.log(equipFailsLogs)
```

This is what goes to the front end. (i run another function to get the whole row each bit of date is associated with and return it as an html table in pug.

```
  return {
    "Results": {
    "coolCount":coolFailsRows.length/2 , coolLogs:coolFailsLogs,
    "heatCount":heatFailsRows.length/2 , heatLogs:heatFailsLogs,
    "miscCount":miscFailsRows.length/2 , miscLogs:miscfailsLogs,
    "equipCount":equipFailsLogs.length/4 , equipLogs:equipFailsLogs,
  }};
}

exports.runThermostat = runThermostat
```

Comment: It's not clear where in your code you are even calling these functions? Of course they have different signatures, you would have to adapt to that.

Comment: You should not have to use `push` if you have `.map` at your disposal. And that array destructuring is really useless when you don't reuse or at least reorder all those variables. You should really simplify that to `function createLogs(array, runtimeArray) { return array.map((currentValue,index) => [index, ...currentValue.slice(1, 10), runtimeArray[index]]); }`

Comment: All the information is pulled from a worksheet, the arrays are populated by searching for a string and if the string on the worksheet matches the term the array is populated with the values in the column. I can't rely on all the data being the same - the first function (createLogs()) draws from the original array with ALL of the data in the work sheet, createResults draws its information from the columns themselves.

Comment: Yes, and somewhere in that code you messed up. The error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.` does not come from any of the code you posted.

Comment: It could come from either `for item in equipFailsResultLog` or `for item in equipArray`, i.e. either `equipFailsResultLog` or `equipArray` is `undefined`. Where does `result` come from?

Comment: I agree, the error is about something else. `tfoot 140| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.` mentions `tfoot` - could it be related to code you did not post, or the fact that the footer is empty for your chosen template engine?

Comment: I'm using pug - should I remove the footer I haven't used it yet.